# NodeJS context issues

Tags: sqlite, node.js, http

I'm having issues with writing to a socket (with http) from a sqlite (sqlite3) libary in Node.JS

https://gist.github.com/RyanCopley/6004c3ce372e060bbf18

Lines 68 to 75, I have 4 attempts to write. Outside of the db.each, everything works in any context. INSIDE of it, it crashes miserably. I'm not entirely sure why, but I feel like there is a conflict between the two libraries

BTW I already know concatenating the SQL statement is bad :3

Comment: What errors are you getting when you say it "crashes miserably"?

Comment: I feel like i've gone insane. Now, it's not crashing at all, but it still isn't writing out to the buffer, even with the that.res.write context. Before, it was saying it couldn't find the write() function.

Comment: Oh. When I remove this.res = res, I get this error:https://gist.github.com/RyanCopley/4fec6076f799ac0e7496

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the callback function in `db.each` is called *asynchronously*. This means that line 79: `res.end()` will be called before `res.write("Found row!");`, triggering an error.

I think what you want to do is something like this:

```
db.serialize(function() {
    that.res.write("["); // works
    db.each("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE channel = '"+q.chan+"' AND id > "+q.since+" ORDER BY id", function(err, row) {
        res.write("Found row!"); //does not work
        that.res.write("Found row!"); //does not work
        console.log("Found row!");
    });

    res.write("]");//works
});
```